# Scala type parameter inference based on return type (function vs method)

Tags: scala, type-inference, typeclass, scala-implicits

I try to create a small matching library in Scala.
I have the following type representing a matcher that reprsents a constraint on a type `T`:

```
trait Matcher[-T] extends (T => Boolean)
```

and a `matches` function that checks whether that constraint holds on a given instance:

```
def matches[A](x: A, m: Matcher[A]) = m(x)
```

With this I would like to be able to write checks like:

```
matches(Option(1), contains(1))
matches(Seq(1,2), contains(1))
```

where the `contains` can abstract over any *container*. I tried the following abstraction using type classes:

```
trait F[-C[_]] {
  def contains[A >: B, B](c: C[A], x: B): Boolean 
}
```

which I can then use to define `contains` function:

```
def contains[A, B[A]](y: A)(implicit f: F[B]): Matcher[B[A]] = new Matcher[B[A]] {
  override def apply(v1: B[A]): Boolean = f.contains(v1, y)
}
```

with two implicit definitions, one for `Option`:

```
implicit object OptionF extends F[Option] {
  override def contains[A >: B, B](c: Option[A], x: B): Boolean = c.contains(x)
}
```

and for `Iterable`:

```
implicit object IterableF extends F[Iterable] {
  override def contains[A >: B, B](c: Iterable[A], x: B): Boolean = c.exists(_ == x)
}
```

However, when I get the errors on each call to `matches`. They are all the same:

```
Error:(93, 39) ambiguous implicit values:
both object OptionF in object MatchExample of type MatchExample.OptionF.type
and object IterableF in object MatchExample of type MatchExample.IterableF.type
match expected type MatchExample.F[B]
matches(Option(1), contains(1))
```

It seems that the type inference could not deduce the type properly and that is why both implicit matches.

How can the `matches` function be defined without ambiguity?

I also tried to use implicit conversion to add the `matches` function directly to any type:

```
implicit class Mather2Any[A](that:A) {
  def matches(m: Matcher[A]): Boolean = m(that)
}
```

and that is working just fine:

```
Option(x1) matches contains(x1)
lx matches contains(x1)
lx matches contains(y1)
```

What I don't understand why the `matches` functions does not work while the method does? It looks like the problem is that the inference is only based on the return type. For example instead of `contains` I could `isEmpty` with not arguments which again works with the `matches` method but not function.

The full code listing is in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/fikovnik/fcc54e2b869bc79ed7341fe2b62f0363).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is to split the parameters into two lists:

```
def matches[A](x: A)(m: Matcher[A]) = m(x)

matches(Option(1))(contains(1))
matches(Seq(1,2))(contains(1))
```

`A` gets inferred from `x` and is then available while type-checking `m`. With `Mather2Any` you have the same situation.

Side note: variations on this get asked often, I just find it faster to reply than to find a duplicate.